# 5 cards can be drawn from a single deck of 52 cards

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, card-games

What is the number of ways that 5 cards can be drawn from a single deck of 52 cards?Is it 52c5 or 52p5 ???

Comment: Could be either, depending if they want to hear the number of ways *with* or *without* taking into the account the order in which the cards are drawn. I would say the problem is ambiguously worded and needs a clarification.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The order of the cards does not matter, There is only single deck (52 cards), 5 cards to be drawn

Comment: I also assume this is a single deck of 52 cards, and 5 cards are drawn. However, the question is: do you count one draw such as (5 hearts, A diamonds, 3 hearts, 2 clubs, K spades) the same or different as another possible draw (A diamonds, 5 hearts, 3 hearts, 2 clubs, K spades) - the same cards drawn but in a different order. That is the key. If you count them as different, the answer is 52p5, if you count them as identical, the answer is 52c5.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you, You have solved my query.